# Hecke operators on q-expansion of cusp forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I am trying the following exercise.

> Let $V=S_2(\Gamma _1 (16))$ and we are given the following basis of $V$, their $q$ expansion at the $\infty $ cusp.
> \begin{align}
> f_1 =&  q − 2q^3 − 2q^4 + 2q^6 + 2q^7 + 4q^8 − q^9 + O(q^{10}), \\
> f_2  =& q^2 − q^3 − 2q^4 + q^5 + 2q^7 + 2q^8 − q^9 + O(q^{10}).  
> \end{align}
> Show that $S_2(\Gamma _1 (8))=\{0\}$ and $S_2(\Gamma _1(16))_{new}=V$.

I don't know how to prove that $S_2(\Gamma _1 (8)=\{0\}$. The dimension formula involves genus and I don't know how to compute the genus of $X_1(8)$. But once this is done, it follows immediately that $V= S_2(\Gamma _1 (16))_{new}$.

Next exercise is to

> Compute the matrix of the operator $T_2$.

Now, I could use the formula $$ a_m(T_n)=\sum _{d|(m,n)} a_{(m,n)/d^2}(\langle d \rangle f)$$ since I have the $q$-expansions and look at first few coefficients. But how is this enough since I only know the $q$-expansions till $O(q^{10})$?